# Insert Data in multiple table using if(mysql_query)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm beginner in PHP MySQL. I would like ask how can I use this code for `INSERT DATA IN MULTIPLE TABLES`  I will be using this in Single FORM.

**Here is my working code for single table:**

```
     if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
     //table 1
     $variable1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column1']);
     $variable2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column2']);
     $variable3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column3']);
     //table 2
     $var1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['columnT1']);
     $var2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['columnT2']);
     $var3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['columnT3']);



 if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName( column1, column2, column3 )
      VALUES ('$variable1, '$variable2', '$variable3' )"))      
{
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">('ADDED SUCCESFULLY!');</script>
  <?php
} else {
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">('Failed!');</script>    
<?php
```

**But I want to add new code for INSERT to another table.** 
I tried like but still error.

```
     if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName( column1, column2, column3 )
      VALUES ('$variables', '$variable2', '$variable3' )")

    ("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
      VALUES ('$var1', '$var2, '$var3' )"))
```

Comment: you are using mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
      VALUES ('$var1, $var2, $var3' )"))

Comment: start using PDO or mysqli. and ou can run the same insert again pointing to your new table with appropriate column.

Comment: if your values are string put then inside quotes while inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This one..

```
 if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName( column1, column2, column3 )
      VALUES ('$variable1', '$variable2', '$variable3' )"))    // '$variable1' 
{
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('ADDED SUCCESFULLY!');</script> // add alert()
  <?php
} else {
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">alert('Failed!');</script>  // add alert()   
<?php }?>

second table :- ("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
  VALUES ('$var1', '$var2, '$var3' )"));
```

You can `Echo` the query like

```
echo  ("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
  VALUES ('$var1', '$var2, '$var3' )")) or die(mysql_error());
```

or

```
echo  ("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
  VALUES ('$var1', '$var2, '$var3' )"));

INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 ) VALUES ('var1', 'var2, 'var3' ) // out put
```

You can check what output generate the query or error an copy the generate query and run in the

```
phpmyadmin > select database > table > Sql > paste there > Go
```

if Its not work then tell me

Comment: Wait. where is the `INSERT` in the 2nd TABLE?

Comment: `second table :- ("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
  VALUES ('$var1', '$var2, '$var3' )"));`  is this right? no comment?

Comment: bro, You asked for second table then as you did put first table and put second table query in that code. if you do have any error or any problem then tell.

Comment: 2 times? `mysql_query` ?

Comment: As You do have  mentioned **INSERT INTO tableName** and **INSERT INTO tableName2** in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `mysql_query()` again

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName( column1, column2, column3 ) {
  VALUES ('$variable1, $variable2, $variable3' )"))      
    echo 'Success insert into tableName';
} else {
    echo 'Failed insert into tableName';
}

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
  VALUES ('$var1, $var2, $var3' )")) {
    echo 'Success insert into tableName2';
} else {
    echo 'Failed insert into tableName2';
}
```

But its still very procedural, and output here should not be with JS. I suggest you start reading [OOP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objektorientierte_Programmierung) and [MVC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller)

Comment: I forgot to say, It was for 1 single form. It is okay to use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes around your values. And use `mysql_affected_rows` to check you row is inserted or not

```
<?php

$query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName( column1, column2, column3)
      VALUES('".$variables."','". $variable2."','". $variable3."')");
$row=mysql_affected_rows();
if($row>0){
    echo "INSERT SUCESSFULLY";
}else{
    echo "ERROR";
}

$query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
      VALUES ('".$var1."', '".$var2."', '".$var3."' )");

$row1=mysql_affected_rows();
if($row1>0){
    echo "INSERT SUCESSFULLY";
}else{
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: It is okay to use in single form?

Comment: Yes it is okk with single form

Comment: below `$query2` I will be using the same code as `$query1` ?

Comment: yes you can use `mysql_affected_rows` to check data is inserted or not

Comment: have error sir, `Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean`

Comment: Ahh my mistake` mysql_affected_rows();` remove $query1

Comment: what do you mean remove $query1?

Comment: just use as `$query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName( column1, column2, column3)
      VALUES('".$variables."','". $variable2."','". $variable3."')");
$row=mysql_affected_rows();`

Comment: How about the `$query2` and the echo?

Comment: @Saty
You do know that method is vunerable to sql injection?

Comment: Actually I don't sql injection issue I will be use this for localhost only hehehe.

Comment: @MuthaFury have you check OP question already use `mysql_real_escape_string` before insert into database

Comment: @Saty and the mysql is deprecated?

Comment: @Saty Error in query2

Answer (score 1):

May I know the error that you are facing while execute the page can try add `mysql_query` before second insert query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
  VALUES ('$var1, $var2, $var3' )"))
```

Comment: `if(! mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
  VALUES ('$var1, $var2, $var3' )")) )  echo  mysql_error();` put this.  Let me know the result

Comment: `'$var1, $var2, $var3'` is wrong it should be:`'$var1', '$var2', '$var3'`

Comment: if you got error while execute mysql query function put **mysql_error();** is help to find the errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "databasename");
```

**Solution 1:**

You have to do it in separate [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) calls:

```
if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tableName( column1, column2, column3 ) VALUES ('$variables', '$variable2', '$variable3' )") && mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 ) VALUES ('$var1', $var2', '$var3' )"))
{
...
}
```

When using two `mysqli_query` calls you should take a look at [mysql transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php).

**Solution 2:**

Use [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php):

```
if(mysqli_multi_query($con, "INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
  VALUES ('$var1', '$var2', '$var3'); INSERT INTO tableName2( columnT1, columnT2, columnT3 )
      VALUES ('$var1', $var2', '$var3')"))
{
...
}
```

When using `mysqli` you should use [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of using the php variables directly in your SQL string. This will help you to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks. but I would like to use it first in MySQL

Comment: Why recommend MySQLi when creating the SQL statement manually? It's as just as insecure as using regular MySQL module that way... (also note that the SQL statement is wrong anyway... `'$var1, $var2, $var3'` should be replaced with `'$var1', '$var2', '$var3'`)

Comment: @AlejandroIván thanks for the hints! I haven't used prepared statement because I wanted to focus on how to execute two statements at once. I added references to `mysql_prepare` and `mysql_stmt_bind_param`. I also added the missing single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do inserts to multiple tables in one statement. But you can use transactions.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tableName (column1,column2,column3) VALUES ('$variable1','$variable2','$variable3');
INSERT INTO tableName2 (column1,column2,column3) VALUES ('$var1','$var2','$var3');
COMMIT;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this may seems complicated for you, but it is better :)

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "<username>", "<password>", "<database>");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {

// Your tables here
$tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');

for ($x=0; $x < 3; $x++) {

switch ($x) {
    // Escape user inputs for security and your columns
    case "1":
    $values[$tables[$x]] = array(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['column1']), mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['column2']), mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['column3']));    
    $columns[$tables[$x]] = array('columnT1', 'columnT2', 'columnT3');
    break;

    case "2":
    $values[$tables[$x]] = array(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['columnT1']), mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['columnT2']), mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['columnT3'])); 
    $columns[$tables[$x]] = array('columnT1', 'columnT2', 'columnT3');
    break;

    case "3":
    $values[$tables[$x]] = array(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['columnT1']), mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['columnT2']), mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['columnT3'])); 
    $columns[$tables[$x]] = array('columnT1', 'columnT2', 'columnT3');
    break;
}

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tables[$x]." (".$columns[$tables[$x]][0].", ".$columns[$tables[$x]][1].", ".$columns[$tables[$x]][2].") VALUES ('".$values[$tables[$x]][1]."', '".$values[$tables[$x]][2]."', '".$values[$tables[$x]][3]."')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully for ".$tables[$x].".";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```